# Поочерёдный доступ к скрипту php

Tags: php

Есть скрипт, когда его запускают 50 человек одновременно, сервак отдаёт 503. Т.е. не хватает ресурсов на одновременную обработку. Как сделать так, чтобы все эти 50 обращений стали в очередь и выполнялись друг за другом. Тем самым распределив нагрузку на сервер.

Comment: что там ваш скрипт делает,  если его на 50 человек не хватает? на уровне сервера такое решать надо, а не пхп. ну и в целом это костыль какой-то. Ладно еще 500 человек,  или 5тысяч, но не 50 же.

Comment: скрипт большой, не HeloWorld. Как можно все обращения ставить в очередь и потом выполнять скрипт, как придёт очередь? на php или на сервере?

Comment: Почему Вы считаете, что тут нужна очередь? Посмотрите в сторону кэширования, оптимизации сервера и т.д., очереди вообще не про это